# Setting data in the Cloned Seismic Cube

Tags: ocean

I am quite new to Ocean Framework. I had cloned a pre-existing seismic cube to create a new seismic cube .

```
// Getting the Parent Cube
SeismicCube ParentCube = InputSeismicLine3D.SeismicCube;
// Getting the Seismic Collection
SeismicCollection Sc = ParentCube.SeismicCollection;

//
if (Sc.CanCreateSeismicCube(ParentCube))
{
SeismicCube NewCube = Sc.CreateSeismicCube(ParentCube, ParentCube.Template);
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to set the trace data in the "NewCube". 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SeismicCube` has `Traces` property.

From the SDK:

> Writing is only possible for cubes, which return `IsWritable` as true and the cube is locked in a transaction. Trace value changes (like `trace[12] = 123.0`) are flushed automatically at regular intervals when you advance to the next trace with `enumerator.MoveNext()`. The value range is recomputed when you finish iterating (`MoveNext()` returns `false`).

In your example:

```
if (Sc.CanCreateSeismicCube(ParentCube))
{
    SeismicCube NewCube = Sc.CreateSeismicCube(ParentCube, ParentCube.Template);
    if (!NewCube.IsWriteable) 
        return;

    using (ITransaction trans = DataManager.NewTransaction()) {
        trans.Lock(NewCube);
        foreach (ITrace trace in NewCube.Traces)
        {
            //Do some setting of trace values here. Example only:
            for (int i = 0; i < trace.Length; i++)
            {
                trace[i] = trace.I + trace.J + i;
            }
        }
        trans.Commit();
    }
}
```